# Problema con number_format al guardar en mysql

Tags: php

Tengo un problema al almacenar numeros con decimales en mysql.

resulta que para mostrarlo en un input convierto la cantidad a formato español con millares separados por . y decimales por , y lo hago así:

```
number_format($Precio,2,",",".");
```

y para almacenarlo en mysql le cambio la , por un punto asi:

```
'".str_replace(",",".",$_POST["Precio"])."'
```

Pero me encuentro con el problema cuando el valor tiene millares ya que la respuesta me viene con un . separando los millares con lo que si el valor son 1.000,30 me guarda 1.00 en mysql.

He pensado en suprimir los . con str_replace antes de cambiar la , por un punto, pero me parece una solución un poco sucia.

¿hay alguna forma mas elegante de hacer esto?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes perfectamente quitar los puntos de la cadena y reemplazar la coma por el punto decimal. Es una solución válida y quizá la menos costosa.

Si te parece *fea*, puedes crear una hermosa función de sólo dos líneas:

```
function strToDecimal($valor){
    $decimal = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $valor));
    return $decimal;
}
```

Vamos a probarla:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/MZY92429)**</kbd>

```
$numero = "1.000,30";
$decimal=strToDecimal($numero);
echo $decimal.PHP_EOL;

$numero = "10.000,99";
$decimal=strToDecimal($numero);
echo $decimal.PHP_EOL;

$numero = "9.999.999,99";
$decimal=strToDecimal($numero);
echo $decimal.PHP_EOL;
```

### Salida:

```
1000.30
10000.99
9999999.99
```

Ahí tienes valores totalmente válidos para insertar como `DECIMAL` en cualquier manejador de Bases de Datos.

---

**NOTA:**

Este tipo de funciones pueden ser incorporadas a una `Clase` utilitaria, en programas donde necesitamos hacer este tipo de operaciones en varios escenarios.

Comment: ¿por que el php_eol?

Comment: @killpe `PHP_EOL` es una de las llamadas [constantes predefinidas](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php) de PHP. Representa el salto de línea. Y usarlo te permitirá escribir código para cualquier plataforma. Ya que en Windows, Mac OS y Linux, hay ciertos comportamientos que no se expresan del mismo modo. El salto de línea es precisamente uno de ellos.